# google drive api for android delay retrieve created file

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api, drive

What I'm trying to do here - is to create a file in my drive via Google Drive Api and retrieve/restore when the file is ready

I use this function bellow to create file :

```
    private void sendToDrive(File file,String nameFile){       
     getDriveResourceClient()
            .createContents()
            .continueWithTask(task -> {
                DriveContents contents = task.getResult();
                OutputStream outputStream = contents.getOutputStream();
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }

                MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                        .setTitle(nameFile)
                        .setStarred(true)
                        .build();

                return getDriveResourceClient().createFile(AppFolder, changeSet, contents);
            }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DriveFile>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(DriveFile driveFile) {

                   Log.e("sendFile","onSuccess");
                }
            }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DriveFile>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DriveFile> task) {
                    Log.e("sendFile", "OnComplete");
                }
            });


}
```

When I call this function for a file I can see both log OnComplete and OnSuccess.

But just after that if I list the files in the folder - I cannot find the file ( especially if it is a big file )

I use this method to get the list of all files in a the drive folder in question:

```
protected void getAllFileFromDrive(){
    DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult metadataBufferResult = AppFolder.listChildren(getDriveClient().asGoogleApiClient()).await();

    if (!metadataBufferResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
        metadataBufferResult.release();
    }else
    {

        MetadataBuffer metadataBuffer = metadataBufferResult.getMetadataBuffer();
        if (metadataBuffer.getCount() == 0) {
            metadataBuffer.release();
        }else{

            for (int i = 0 ; i < metadataBuffer.getCount(); i++)
            {
                Metadata item = metadataBuffer.get(i);
               if (item==null || item.getOriginalFilename()== null)
                    continue;
                Log.e("File",item.getOriginalFilename());
            }
            metadataBuffer.release();
            metadataBufferResult.release();
        }

    }

}
```

But I don't find the file in the log, so I need wait some time so I can see it.
I tried to call syncRequest, and nothing changed, I need to wait like 1 minutes or more ( if the file is more big ).
I can understand that drive is doing some stuff with my file in the background , but I'll like to know when he is done or wait until he done all the process.

All my code is for Android using Drive API with `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:17.0.0'`
 in my gradle ( and it deprecated ).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You know that GDAA has be [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/deprecation).

Drive updates the server according to its own schedule. It's been a while, but I don't think that there is much you can do to influence that schedule. My thought is that the delay is due to Drive uploading your file and not any real significant processing on the backend.

You can be informed of completion of the upload by monitoring [completion events](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/completion) if I recall correctly.